# Will Splinter Twin and Combat Celebrant provide an indeterminant number of combat phases?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

If [Combat Celebrant](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bCombat%20Celebrant%5d) is enchanted with [Splinter Twin](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bSplinter%20Twin%5d), and tapped during the Beginning of Combat portion of the Combat Phase to produce a token that is a Copy of Combat Celebrant, could this result in an indeterminant number of combat phases?

Chain of events:

- **Beginning of Combat**: Tap enchanted Combat Celebrant to generate the token copy.
- **Declare Attackers**: Declare the Token Copy and any number of other creatures attacking. Exert the Token Copy, untapping all other creatures including the original Combat Celebrant.
- **Declare Blockers:** Opponents involvement.
- **Combat Damage:** no surprises.
- Additional Combat Phase Happens: Return to Beginning of Combat above, repeating the cycle.

Comment: I think "unlimited" or "arbitrary" may be a more appropriate word than "indeterminate", not that it's a big deal.

Comment: @DavidZ I didn't want to say infinite/unlimited, because that really isn't a thing in Magic. I'd consider arbitrary though.

Comment: Infinity isn't a thing in Magic, but "unlimited" is - it means that there is no limit on the number of times you can go through a loop. That being said, I personally do prefer "arbitrary". (Whereas "indeterminate" means something pretty different)

Answer (score 9):

**Yes, you can have an infinite amount of combat phases with [Combat Celebrant](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bCombat%20Celebrant%5d) and [Splinter Twin](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bSplinter%20Twin%5d).**

As long as you are exerting a new splinter twin copied Combat Celebrant each time, your enchanted Combat Celebrant will be untapped and able to create a new token. This is covered in the gatherer rulings on Combat Celebrant:

> If you exert multiple Combat Celebrants in one combat phase, you’ll have that many additional combat phases, but all of your creatures are untapped only during the current combat phase. **You’ll need to exert the Combat Celebrants one at a time, in multiple combat phases, to untap your attacking creatures and attack with them in each combat step.**

Comment: This combo also works with [Kiki-Jiki, Mirror Breaker](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=397698) if you want something modern legal.

Comment: I expected as much, just wanted to pre-empt tunnel vision. A modern legal endeavor is even better.